# Recursively execute a locally defined python script on remote machines

Tags: python, ssh

I'm interested in writing a script so that the only copy of the script resides on my local machine, but the script executes on remote machines, possibly with the remote machines executing the script on other remote machines (i.e., 2 or more levels of recursion in the distributed invocation tree).

One way to achieve this would be to copy the script to the remote machines in one step and then perform remote execution via ssh in a second step, passing appropriate parameters to the script, which will pass different parameters for each remote invocation, each of which would be performed via something like:

```
subprocess.call(['ssh', <user@address>, 'python scriptname.py <params>'])
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one step without first copying the python script. Obviously, I'd still have to transmit the code in the script as part of the remote call in some way, but it would be preferable not to have to run two separate commands and perhaps even a third to clean up the file from the remote machine after the script is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be able accomplish this in one step (except for `python -c 'print "hello world"'` maybe). But [fabric](http://fabfile.org) might make your life a little easier.

Comment: Thanks, I have a proof of concept using `-c` and passing the script source code as an argument for use in the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

The Python binary does have a `-c` option that lets you pass in valid Python code as an argument. For example:

```
$ python -c "print 'hello'; print 'world'"
```

prints

```
hello
world
```

Your script may have dependencies or be too complex for this, but it does handle more trivial commands.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) does this "bootstrapping" as part of its normal execution. It assumes the existence of a Python interpreter on the remote end of an ssh connection, and uploads code to run.

I haven't investigated the code to find out exactly what it does, but it should be reasonably straightforward to find.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org).  It's the Python tool to "write and execute Python functions, or tasks, to automate interactions with remote servers." [#](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/tutorial.html)